# Java SIGSEGV when starting a Jenkins Job on Debian 8

Tags: java, jenkins, debian, java-6

i have a problem with jenkins and java on debian 8. My jenkins job compiles some java source, but sometimes, not in every build, a java causes a SIGSEGV.

Some details:

- Debian 8 x64
- Jenkins 1.641
- JDK: openjdk8
- Ant: 1.9.6

For compiling, it is required that i use jdk 1.6. I've tested with (oracle) jdk 1.6.0u39_x64 up to 1.6.0u45_x64, always getting the same error, a SIGSEGV message:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc9f87fb160, pid=30156, tid=140505482675968

JRE version: 6.0_39-b04
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  0x00007fc9f87fb160      [svn] <Status> finished.
```

Can anyone tell me how to prevent this SIGSEGV error?

The full error message is available at: http://pastebin.com/c9a69FEg

Thank you.

Regards,
Mani

Comment: Jenkins needs Java 7 or above.  How come your crash has java 6 in it?   First pdate operating system with all patches. The ensure Jenkins is using correct Java.

Comment: As described above, jenkins uses openjdk8. For compiling *my sources* i have to use java 6, not for jenkins. The SIGSEGV is caused by java 6.

Comment: How does it compile your code? Maven?   Please share details about your job. Could you share the full crash log ?

Comment: I use an ant task to compile the sources. The full log message is [here](http://pastebin.com/c9a69FEg).

If you need any further information, please tell me.